# Connect SQL Server 2012 with Symfony2

Tags: sql-server, symfony, sql-server-2012, php-5.6

I want to connect my project Symfony2 with SQL Server, so I downloaded the Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server from this link: https://www.microsoft.com/en-za/download/details.aspx?id=20098

and I extract it into `wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\bin` and I restarted the wamp server.

But when I want to create my database and my tables from my symfony project I got this error :

> [PDOException]
>   SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user
>   'PC-RAMI\rami'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

This is my `parameters.yml` file :

```
parameters:
    database_driver: pdo_sqlsrv
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: null
    database_name: test
    database_user: PC-RAMI\rami
    database_password: "password of my PC"
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
    secret: a5142e8af29ca527a8d9f3a6993ba894c4bf5ed9
```

[this is the authentication interface of sql server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCE1V.png)

Comment: Quote: 3. When prompted, enter the path to the PHP extensions directory 4. After extracting the files, read the Installation section of the SQLSRV32_Readme.htm file for next steps. You need to put the dll into the PHP Extensions folder, not apache.

Comment: thanks for your response, I have added the dll into the PHP Extension but unfortunately I get the same error.

Comment: we use [realestateconz/mssql-bundle](https://github.com/realestateconz/MssqlBundle)

Comment: @ram did you add the extension to the php.ini?

Comment: @ram Are you using app_dev.php? Because your configuration looks good. If you have problem with sqlsrv installation it should throw a little bit different exception. If you are using production version app.php you maybe use pdo_mysql because your parameters.yml is cached. Anyway, check phpinfo and look for sqlsrv. You have to install sqlsrv first (if you havent't yet) then try advice from my post below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL server uses [two methods for login](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144284.aspx).

- **SQL Server Authentication** - you have to provide username and password (same like for MySQL etc.). If you want to use it, you have to configure your SQL server for mixed authentication. Default user is sa.
- **Windows Authentication** - you want to use credentials of some local/domain Windows account.

You are trying to use the second method (I guess from your screenshot). **Solution is setting up username and password to null (~ in YAML)**.

```
database_user: ~
database_password: ~
```

The reason is in sqlsrv extension. [If you provide username and password it always tries to connect by SQL Server Authentication instead of Windows Authentication](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php). But, what will PHP use as credentials? It takes credentials from process itself. Probably, you will have to run Apache2 under target credentials.

If your SQL server is configured in mixed mode. You can also [create new database](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337545.aspx) user account (not coming from any Windows account) and use standard username/password approach.

Comment: thanks @kba I have  set the database_user and database_password to null and it works